# Error installing program on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, installation, macbook

I am using Windows 7 Professional 64-bit with Boot Camp with a Macbook Pro.

I am attempting to install an older program, Meteonorm 40, that appears to be 32-bit only. It fails while trying to install and I get an error message that is called

```
Unsupported 16-Bit Application
```

**The error message reads:**

```
The program or feature "\??\C:\USERS\KKHOOGEN\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\~EXB0000
\DISK1\SETUP.EXE" cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 
64-bit version of Windows.  Please contact the software vendor to ask 
if a 64-bit Windows compatible version is available.
```

Is there a suggested way to install something that rejects 64-bit? Can I fool it? Should I fool it?

Comment: The error message indicates that Meteonorm is actually 16 bit rather than 32 bit.

Answer (score 2):

Your application is a 16-bit app, not a 32-bit app. In Vista they warned everyone that 16-bit support was going to go away - and go away it did in Windows 7.

Because you have Windows 7 Pro (for later readers all "higher" versions - Business, Ultimate, etc. - support this as well) you can use XP Mode to run older apps in an XP Virtual Machine. [Paul Thurrott has a good article on this.](http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/xp_mode_rc.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Is upgrading [Meteonorm](http://www.meteonorm.com/) to a newer version an option?

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question can be found in [this post.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproappcompat/thread/e94fdaad-9779-4e2d-865a-bd2d797173cc)  It will take a little bit of work, but you should be able to do it :)