# Use dosbox to run 16-bit program on 64-bit

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, dosbox, 16-bit

After reading a lot about how to use dosbox and virtual machines to run older programs on x-64 I found myself in another situation.

I have a 32-bit program that runs correctly, but calls a 16-bit program. So whenever I try to use that function, the program give me the error.

Is it possible to have this program to always run using dosbox? I noticed it works with dosbox, but it should be called from within another program.

references I already read:

[Unsupported 16-bit application](https://superuser.com/questions/556831/unsupported-16-bit-application)

[Force a program to run on x86?](https://superuser.com/questions/872660/force-a-program-to-run-on-x86/872661#872661)

[Error installing program on Windows 7 64-bit](https://superuser.com/questions/58081/error-installing-program-on-windows-7-64-bit)

[Run 16 bit program on 64 machine bit without dosbox](https://superuser.com/questions/529783/run-16-bit-program-on-64-machine-bit-without-dosbox)

[Run 16 bit program on 64 machine bit without dosbox](https://superuser.com/questions/529783/run-16-bit-program-on-64-machine-bit-without-dosbox)

[running 16-bit code on 64-bit OS, using virtualization](https://superuser.com/questions/894829/running-16-bit-code-on-64-bit-os-using-virtualization)

[Is it possible to run an old 16-bit DOS application under Windows 7 64-bit?](https://superuser.com/questions/333103/is-it-possible-to-run-an-old-16-bit-dos-application-under-windows-7-64-bit)

[How do I get 16-bit programs to work on a 64-bit Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/264090/how-do-i-get-16-bit-programs-to-work-on-a-64-bit-windows)

[Why can't a 64 bit OS run a 16 bit application?](https://superuser.com/questions/140953/why-cant-a-64-bit-os-run-a-16-bit-application)

---

So basically dosbox is an option, but How could I force the program to be run in dosbox whenever it is called?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a program that calls it it in DosBox. Then rename the 16-bit executable to `progname.old.exe`, and rename your new program to `progname.exe`. Here is an example program (Note: this is untested. It might not even compile.):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // The string we use to call DOSBOX:
    const char *dosboxstrstart = "path\\to\\dosbox \"path\\to\\progname.old.exe ";
    const char *dosboxstrend = "\" -exit";

    // Get the entire command line, with a full path prepended
    // to the first argument
    char *allcmdline = GetCommandLine();

    // Get a pointer to the start of this program's name, then
    // skip past this program's name to get the arguments only
    char *argstart = strstr(allcmdline, argv[0]) + strlen(argv[0]);

    // Get the length of the argument string
    // Get the length of the DosBox strings
    size_t argstartlen = str_len(argstart);
    size_t dosboxstrstartlen = str_len(dosboxstrstart);
    size_t dosboxstrendlen = str_len(dosboxstrend);

    // Create a buffer for the string to go into (+1 for the \0)
    // Assumes that malloc won't go wrong; a lovely segfault
    // will occur if it does! :-p
    char *finalstring = malloc(argstartlen + dosboxstrstartlen + dosboxstrendlen + 1);

    // Put the string into it, piece by piece
    memcpy(finalstring, dosboxstrstart, dosboxstrstartlen);
    memcpy(finalstring + dosboxstrstartlen, argstart, argstartlen);
    memcpy(finalstring + dosboxstrstartlen + argstartlen, dosboxstrend, dosboxendlen + 1);

    // Run the command
    system(finalstring);

    // Perform our duty to the almighty kernel!
    free(finalstring);
}
```

This code assumes that the arguments that the 32-bit program passes do not contain quotes. If they do, you'll have to add some sort of escaping function, and I don't know of any in the standard library.